# How I can pass to value to a link in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to MVC Razor and I have this problem

Ex:

I want to pass a value to id, so this is what I did:

```
<a href="https://ag.de/goto.asp?id=@Model.LinkDirect"></a>
```

Can anyone tell me it is right or wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? What does it output?

Comment: just try it in your code and run it and see what happens

Comment: That looks correct. Are you receiving some kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use parenthesis around your razor code if you are using @Razor syntax and want to embed it in a string with no spaces.

assuming that you are passing in the correctly populated Model, try the following:

```
<a href="https://ag.de/goto.asp?id=@(Model.LinkDirect)">My direct link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text between opening and closing anchor tag like this : `<a href="https://ag.de/goto.asp?id=@(Model.LinkDirect)">Click here</a>`